# Сбросить форму за элементом?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть такой HTML код:

```
<div class="addMore"></div>
<div class="adProfInner">
   <div class="formAdd"><form></form></div>
</div>
```

По клику на `addMore` нужно сбросить форму в контейнере `formAdd`

Вот таков код не сработал:

```
$(this).next('.adProfInner').find('form').trigger('reset');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваш код работает прекрасно:

```
$('.addMore').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).next('.adProfInner').find('form').trigger('reset');
});
```

Пример тут: http://jsfiddle.net/8rvz27jt/2/

Comment: Да - для инпута работает, но если есть select - то нет

Answer (score 1):

Для select тоже отлично работает:
http://jsfiddle.net/8rvz27jt/3/

Comment: Отредактировал Ваш пример с применением `selected="selected"`
http://jsfiddle.net/8rvz27jt/4/ Не работает

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, конечно, не работает. А знаете почему? Потому что и стандартный `input[type=reset]` тоже не работает.  

Убедитесь сами: http://jsfiddle.net/8rvz27jt/5/  

В вашем случае нужно не `reset` делать а удалять атрибут.

Comment: Видимо, особенности браузера - у меня на selected и trigger и кнопка type=reset срабатывают - последний хром. Где вы проверяете?

Comment: @Михаил Ямаев, Firefox Developer Edition

Comment: @VenZell, попробуйте http://jsfiddle.net/8rvz27jt/6/ - тут trigger заменен на метод reset для формы